# how to use telescopes `previewers` functions?

Tags: neovim, telescope

I would really love to make use of this function

```
previewers.git_commit_diff_to_head() *telescope.previewers.git_commit_diff_to_head()*
    A previewer that shows a diff of a commit to head.
    The run command is `git --no-pager diff --cached $SHA -- $CURRENT_FILE`

    The current file part is optional. So is only uses it with bcommits.
```

but everything i try seems to error out. I've tried putting it in init.lua file as `require('telescope.previewers').git_commit_diff_to_head()` as a mapping inside telescope, as well as a key mapping outside of the init, but neither has worked